# Using BeautifulSoup to exploit a URL and its dependent pages and store results in csv?

Tags: pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

This code does not crash, which is good.  However, it generates and empty **icao_publications.csv** f.  I want to populate **icao_publications.csv** with all record on all the pages from the URL and capture all the pages. The dataset should be about 10,000 rows or their about in all.
I want to get these 10,000 or so rows  in the csv file.

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.icao.int/publications/DOC8643/Pages/Search.aspx'

with open('Test1_Aircraft_Type_Designators.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Manufacturers", "Model", "Type_Designator", "Description", "Engine_Type", "Engine_Count", "WTC"])

    while True:
        html = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
        for row in soup.select('table tbody tr'):
            writer.writerow([c.text if c.text else '' for c in row.select('td')])


        if soup.select_one('li.paginate_button.active + li a'):
            url = soup.select_one('li.paginate_button.active + li a')['href']
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www4.icao.int/doc8643/External/AircraftTypes'
resp = requests.post(url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(resp)
df.to_csv('aircraft.csv',encoding='utf-8',index=False)
print('Saved to aircraft.csv')
```

Comment: Dear bushcat69, just like this, a handful of lines.  Fantastic!  May I ask about the URL, I am not familiar with it?  many thanks.

Comment: If you open your browser's Developer Tools - Network - fetch/Xhr and then reload the page you were trying to scrape you should see a bunch of backend api calls. Those are scrapable themselves. One of them makes a post request to that URL I used and if you look at the Preview tab of that request you'll see a massive file with the 11k-ish planes you wanted. Since it's in a list of dicts it's easy to put into a dataframe and export to csv. Feel free to ask more Qs if you want

Comment: I follow your directions and saw the www4.  Pretty neat stuff.  Thank you!

Comment: Dear bushcat69, in the dataset both French and German characters like à ä è ü exist but the code uses √° instead. Can the code address these two points? Many thanks

Comment: I've edited the code to make sure it uses utf-8 encoding, seems to be working on my side. However you open it on your side also needs to ensure it's using utf-8 encoding (I've opened it in VS-Code and looks good)

Comment: Dear bushcat69, respecting international languages the correct python code to use is  --->df.to_csv('aircraft.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False)